# What are some general strategies to build measure preserving real-analytic diffeomorphisms?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, reference-request, differential-geometry, analyticity

One could prove the following theorem in the smooth setting:

---

**Theorem**

*Let $(M,m)$ be a $d$ dimensional $C^\infty$ manifold with smooth volume $m$. 
Let $\{F_i\}_{i=1}^k$ and $\{G_i\}_{i=1}^k$ be two systems of disjoint open subsets, satisfying $m(F_i)=m(G_i)$. Assume $\bar{F}_i$ and $\bar{G}_i$ are diffeomorphic to the $d$ dimensional closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $i=1,\ldots k$. 
Then, given $\varepsilon>0$ and a compact set $N\subset M$ with $F_i\subset N$  for $i=1,\ldots , k$;  there exists $h\in \text{Diff }^\infty(M,\mu)$ satisfying $m(h(F_i)\Delta G_i)<\varepsilon$.*

---

This theorem is extremely helpful in building diffeomorphisms of smooth manifolds. I do not know a reference but I guess one can prove this using some kind of partition of unity argument.

My question is: What's the best one can do in the real-analytic set up? Of-course the entire business with $N$ needs to be dropped.

Also more generally: What are some general strategies of building real-analytic diffeomorphisms and flows?

Comment: Do you mean there exists $h$ which is measure preserving? Do you have a reference?

Comment: Yes, $h$ can be measure preserving. I do not have the original reference but I took it from here: http://www.personal.psu.edu/axk29/pub/AKConst70.pdf  See theorem 1.1 and 1.2. For real analytic if you drop the requirement of entirity of the complexification, I believe you can do it but much harder (May be soome Moser trick will be needed). But if you restrict $(M,m)$ to he flat torus, I can think it can be done: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.06621.pdf  see theorem E, p36, a finer version of that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for putting up the reference.