# Reference request for texts on a generalization of real algebraic geometry.

Tags: reference-request, real-algebraic-geometry

I know that the field of real algebraic geometry studies zero sets of real polynomials. I am looking for texts on a generalization of real algebraic geometry that talk about zero sets of classes of functions other than polynomials, for example, elementary functions.

Let me give an example of what I mean. Consider the zero set of the function defined by the expression $e^x + \sin(x) + x^3$. Such a function and its associated zero set would not be studied in real algebraic geometry, but it would be studied in a text that generalizes real algebraic geometry. Is there such a text somewhere?

Comment: Something with semianalytic and subanalytic sets

Comment: Are you acquainted with [MetiTarski](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/papers/Arith)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeking for such a "generalization of real algebraic geometry that talk about zero sets of classes of functions other than polynomials" maybe too broader. But there are some answers [in this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633313/is-there-a-field-of-real-analytic-geometry) concerning about what is called "real analitic geometry" (which could be the generalization which you are seeking for).

In addition to the answers there, I recommend [Constructible Sets in Real Geometry](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Carlos-Andradas/dp/3642800262/ref=sr_1_1?crid=WS4ZRF3BV976&keywords=constructible+sets+in+real+algebraic+geomety&qid=1703774026&sprefix=constructible+sets+in+real+algebraic+geomety%2Caps%2C257&sr=8-1) by C. Andradas, L. Bröcker and J. Ruiz. This book deals mostly with the theory of the minimal description of real constructible sets. Its Chapter VIII is devoted to the study of semianalytic sets in real analytic manifolds. Of course, it is not a book for beginners but at least you can consult some key results there and compare them with your needs.